# How to improve failover speed for AWS Global Accelerator or Route53 Latency routing?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, load-balancing, failover

I'm trying to achieve the fastest failover possible on AWS
I have multiple EC2 instances behind 4 ALBs in 4 different regions and have tried these two setups...

1. 4 domain aliases (all `nearest.mydomain.com`), set with **Latency** routing policy to the 4 regions of my ALBs. I then point a Cloudfront distribution to this domain (for https/WAF etc) and tie it to a CNAME `entrypoint.mydomain.com`.
   So I have  `entrypoint.mydomain.com > cloudfront > nearest.mydomain.com > regional ALB`
2. Using Global Accelerator I create 4 Endpoint Groups pointing to my ALBs in their respective regions and then point an alias `entrypoint2.mydomain.com` to the dns name `abcdefg12345.awsglobalaccelerator.com`

Both work, and deliver content to the correct user based on their location. But if I remove instances from one of the ALBs, both entrypoint urls get 503 errors and option 1. is fastest to redirect to another region (about one minute). Global accelerator is slow to respond, even in the health checks in the global accelerator dashboard.

Is there any way I can improve the responsiveness of the health checks and therefore the failover? Global Accelerator talks about instant failover, but I can't seem to get that to work. There's always a minute or two wait. Does anyone know how to improve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

AWS Global Accelerator ingest the load balancer configuration of your regional ALB (see [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/global-accelerator/latest/dg/about-endpoint-groups-health-check-options.html)). From the moment the load balancer is marked unhealthy, it takes Global Accelerator about 30 seconds to start shifting any *new* TCP connection to the next closest, healthy endpoint. Global Accelerator doesn't break active connections. Let me know if you have further questions.